# PHP > read cookies form online users ( Online users )

Tags: php, cookies

I have 10 pages and users database.

In the index I ask the user to select his name from drop-down menu, then I save the value as Cookies.

My target is to show on each page who is online.

My current method is showing only one user, 
I.e : if user A select his name then only his name will be shown in who is online on this page.

I need to show all users

any ideas ?

My code

```
        if(isset($_COOKIE[UserID])) {

        $UserID =   $_COOKIE[UserID];

        $UserRequest = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE user_id ='$UserID' ";
        $UserName = $Connect->query($UserRequest);

        while($row = $AgentName->fetch_assoc()) {
            $FirstName  =   $row["first_name"];

        }
        print "$FirstName";

    } else {


        }
```

Comment: Is there any code you already have tried?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. As it is, this question is way to broad. Btw, why does the user need to select the users own name? Shouldn't you do that for the user?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , I added my code now and currently I dont have a login function so this is to make things faster.

Comment: Ummmm... I've got a feeling you're fundamentally misunderstanding the way this works. No instance of the application knows of any other instance, you can't just build an aggregated list of users from the individual cookies... unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do of course.

Comment: @CD001, I was looking for the following solution: On each page the code check how is browsing this page  by reading the cookies

Comment: You can't do it like that - essentially each user is running their own version of the application. You'd need to store the logged in users in the database and poll it, or use web sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add a new column in your users table called `lastaction`. This column will be updated everytime the user navigates to your website. In this example we are going to show all users that were 'online' the last 5 minutes.

Then you can get the interval `DATE_SUB()` with a query similar like this:

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE lastaction > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) WHERE userid='2'
```

Example in PHP:

```
<?php
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM table WHERE lastaction > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) WHERE userid='2'");
if($query->num_rows == 0)
{
    echo "There are no users online.";

}else{
    echo '<ul>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<li>{$row["username"]}</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

And then update the `lastaction` when the user hits F5 or something.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE lastonline = NOW() WHERE userid='2'");
```

I hope this will help you!

**Note: You need to update this code to your own as this is written as an example.**

Comment: Thanks this Ideas works with me, I added the page id and action time to DB and my method is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp to your user table and update it on every page request. Now you can query and display all users that have requested a page in the last X seconds/minutes.